# Python: How to add a new line with a variable inside of the print function

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

In Python, I'm aware that `'\n'` adds a new line when using a string inside of a `print` call. But how do I add a new line when using a variable inside of the `print` function?

For example:

```
print("\nHello") # <----- string used, no issues here
```

produces

```
>>> print("\nHello")

Hello
```

Now suppose I have a `list` named `guest_list`. How would I do something akin
to "`print('\n'guest_list)`", printing an empty line and then the list?

Thanks for any help offered!

Comment: did any of the answers solve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass an empty string as the first argument and `sep='\n'` if you want to avoid formatting/concatenation before printing.

```
>>> guest_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print('', guest_list, sep='\n')

[1, 2, 3]
```

... or equivalently:

```
>>> print('\n', guest_list, sep='')

[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or convert to string, then add `'\n'` to it:

```
>>> l=[1,2,3]
>>> print('\n'+str(l))

[1, 2, 3]
```